# How to open Authentication Pop up in Outlook web add-in?

Tags: javascript, outlook-web-addins

I am developing Outlook Web Add-in. I want to use Authenticate third party system using OAuth2 API. I tried Outlook Dialog but it was not showing authenticate url in url address. I just want to do similar to http://www.boomerangoutlook.com/.It shows authentication window as new pop up. I just want to copy of its login system.

Thanks
Shyams